# Проблема с доступностью функции в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, архитектура

Всем привет. Я не до конца разобрался с ООП темой в `python` и был бы рад решению моей проблемы.

У меня есть модуль, внутри которого 2 класса. Пускай это будут `FirstClass` и `SecondClass(FirstClass)`.

`FirstClass` имеет `@staticmethod`'ы, чтобы его функции можно было вызывать не передавая `self` аргумент.

`SecondClass` наследуется от `FirstClass` и инициализирует в себе некоторые вещи, которые делает/обрабатывает `FirstClass`.

Ну, то есть он должен. Так я планировал. Но столкнулся с проблемой.

Дело в том, что некоторые функции `FirstClass` вызывает внутри себя (*привет ООП*), что почему-то при инициализировании экземпляра класса `SecondClass` приводит к ошибке типа `NameError`:

> **NamerError**: *name **some_helpful_sub_function_name** is not defiend*.

Архитектура кода такая:

```
class FirstClass:
    @staticmethod
    def sub_function():
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def function():
        sub_function()


class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    def __init(self):
        self.a = self.sub_function()
        self.b = self.function() # тут ошибка типа NameError: name sub_function is not defiend
```

Как можно разрешить эту проблему? Большое спасибо.

## UPD

Функций немного, но даже почему-то их переопределение путём копирования с небольшими изменениями в `SecondClass` не помогла. Хотелось бы разрешить данную проблему без переопределения (если это возможно), то есть грамотно и красиво. Ну и без изменений архитектуры, ибо она распланирована на `Tools`'ы и `AutoWorker`'а, где функции, которые всплывают в исключениях, относятся к классу `Tools`'ов и предназначены для обособленного использования.

**Допускаю** возможность исключить класс `Tools` и засунуть его функции в отдельный модуль, но, к сожалению, не хватает познаний в том, как устроена система файлов для каталога: `__init__.py`, `setup.py` (какие файлы ещё есть?).

Comment: "Допускаю возможность исключить класс Tools и засунуть его функции в отдельный модуль" - в простейшем случае просто выносите функции и классы в отдельный файл py, а потом его по имени подключаете. Если вам не нужен пакет с субмодулями, то `__init__.py` не нужен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Питоне, следует явно указывать полное имя:

```
>>> class FirstClass:
...     @staticmethod
...     def sub_function():
...         pass
...
...     @staticmethod
...     def function():
...         sub_function()  #XXX broken

>>> FirstClass.function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in function
NameError: name 'sub_function' is not defined
name 'sub_function' is not defined
```

Минимальное изменение: используйте `FirstClass.sub_function()`, а не `sub_function()`.

Не используйте `self.sub_function()` -- это будет работать, но вводит в заблуждение (выглядит как вызов обычного метода).

Кроме имени, особой разницы между статическими функциями и функциями, которые вне класса определены нет. Если помещение в пространство имён класса не улучшает читаемость удобство использования (`str.maketrans`) кода, то можно эти функции на уровне модуля определить.

Comment: То есть проблема не решается? Только на уровень модуля переводить всё?

Comment: @KitScribe У вас код в FirstClass неправильный даже без добавления SecondClass ((посмотрите на NameError в ответе, где только FirstClass есть). Я показал как код в FirstClass исправить. Это исправляет вызов и во втором классе (если вы дополнительно исправьте `__init` на `__init__`. Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Если после исправления двух ошибок возникнут ещё ошибки, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, используя classmethod(то же самое что и staticmеthod только 1 аргумент метода это сам класс)

```
class FirstClass:
    @classmethod
    def sub_function(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def function(cls):
        cls.sub_function()


class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    def __init(self):
        self.a = self.sub_function()
        self.b = self.function()
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы функции можно было вызвать обособлено. Грубо говоря, как команды

Comment: Ну дык в чем проблема? Сигнатура вызова метода извне не меняеться. Что с statccimethod что с classmethod FirstClass.function() https://repl.it/HVOC/0